# Javascript - groups array of numbers that are same

Tags: javascript

I have to groups similar numbers into an array.
For Example :

```
var original_Array=[1,1,2,3,3];
```

This is my original array. But i have to split this array like

```
Array_1 = [ 1, 1 ];
Array_2 = [ 2 ];
Array_3 = [ 3, 3 ];
```

How do i split from the original array in java script.

Please find the actual scenario :

```
handleAutoSplit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = this.state.item;
    var lines = item.order_items;
    var lines=item.order_items.splice(0);

    for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
        for ( var k=j+1; k < lines.length; k++) {
            if (lines[j].split_number == lines[k].split_number) {
                var count=0;
                var line = { 
                    line_id: uuidv4(), 
                    split_number:lines[count].split_number, 
                    product_quantity:lines[count].product_quantity 
                };
                item.order_items.push(line);
                count++
            }
            this.setState({ item: item })
        }
    }       
    this.props.create(this.state.item);
    item.order_items.splice(0);
}
```

Comment: You should prob provide something you tried at least

Comment: I have attached the actual scenario, which am facing..

Comment: How does that code relate to the question?

Comment: Am having "Lines" like [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 ]

Comment: var lines = item.order_items; , So i have to create 3 Lines out of it.

Comment: Line_1 = [ 1, 1 ]  ... Line_2=[ 2 ] .... Line_3 = [ 3 , 3 ]

Comment: And what would you do with those three lines? store them in `item`? If so, where? You want `order_items` to become a nested array?

Comment: yes. in mongodb., am using reactjs as front end . Lines is an array in mongodb. And "Orders" is the main collection. so i have to create 3 Orders with Line_1 and 2nd Order with Line_2 and 3rd Order with Line_3

Comment: Have to store 3 different Lines in 3 different Item. Have to create those items simultaneously. Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a `Map`: that way it will also work when your array is not sorted. Build it with `reduce` and then take the values from it with the `Map#values` method:

```js
var a = [1,1,2,3,3];

var res = [...a.reduce ( (acc, v) => acc.set(v, (acc.get(v) || []).concat(v)), 
                        new Map).values()];
  
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For those who prefer non-ES6, non-functional code:

```js
var a = [1,1,2,3,3],
    acc = {},
    res = [],
    i, v;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    v = a[i];
    if (!(v in acc)) {
        acc[v] = [];
    }
    acc[v].push(v);
}
for (v in acc) {
    res.push(acc[v]);
}
  
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Amazing solution, but this kind of code would be a nightmare to maintain - and a headache for your future self.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, Would it really? I think that is a matter of opinion and habbit. This is a very common pattern in *functional programming*, and I I see many other JS posters here on SO who seem comfortable with it just like me.

Comment: The assumption is that the next person after you is fluent in functional programming with JavaScript and understands how ES6 methods work, which I believe does not apply to most people. Just my two cents, development is not code golfing, and you don't get a raise for writing the shortest code that you can't understand after three months.

Comment: It is not my purpose to write the shortest code. This is how I write.

Comment: I understand that many people like to code this way. I do have an idea though, adding some comments should help out people who can't understand it at first glance.

Comment: Instead I added the same in non-functional code, using none of the features that were added in JS in the last fifteen years ;-)